# jquery colorbox - open popup on popup

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using jquery colorbox 1.3.18 with jquery 1.7.2.

My requirement is to open one popup and open another popup from that popup and the previous one should be disabled till i close the last popup. Is this achievable in current version?

Comment: Why dont you just close the first one and then open it again when the user finished the second popup?

Comment: the requirement is such that parent popup will be big and a small child popup will be shown from some event in the parent popup.